# write content of Typed dataset based on XSD compile to database

Tags: xml, xsd, dataset, typed

I'm relatively new to C#, coming from a AS/400 environment.

I have to read and write huge numbers of xml files and I was given a rather complex xsd structure (some 5800 lines, covering some 120 datatables).

After much research I found out how to compile the xsd file using the command prompt. This gave me a typed dataset CS file. I can load and read xml files in this typed dataset (foreach...statement).

The parent child relationships are very clear. I created a sql server database using the XDS2DB tool and some tweeking. The database should have a one to one mapping with the typed dataset.

Question: since the typed dataset was created using the xsd compiler, how can I write the content of the typed dataset to the database ?

Comment: Suppose I create a dataset with the xsd type, fill it with xml records, and merge it with a second typed dataset, created from the database? The second typed dataset woud have all necessary tableadapter(managers) etc...

Comment: Another possibility is to create hundreds of stored procedures (insert/update) and work with sqlcommand and parameters. The root table's auto identity value must be the same in all child tables. There should be a quicker way...